# add "-" after every 6th charater without "-" at the end of the string

Tags: php

I have a 24-long string `$string = "b46844869365d5c9138834b8"`, and I want to add "-" after every 6th character so I have `b46844-869365-d5c913-8834b8`.

I tried following solotions:

```
$string = implode("-", str_split($string,6));

$string = wordwrap($string, 6, '-', true);

$string = chunk_split($string, 6, '-');
```

but they all add a "-" at the end of the result so I get:

```
b46844-869365-d5c913-8834b8-
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its not adding `-` at last.

```
echo wordwrap('b46844869365d5c9138834b8' , 6 , '-' , true );
```

Output:

```
b46844-869365-d5c913-8834b8
```

Comment: thx, I found my mistake, I echoed the `$string` for testing with `.'<br>'` at the end, so I guess this makes `$string` longer and thats why it added a additional "-" at the end.

Comment: By any means, was d answer helpful??

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<?php
$string = "b46844869365d5c9138834b8";
$s = str_split($string,6);
echo implode("-",$s);
?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.